# Из-за чего Get-запрос в insomnia выдает ошибку 401, если я авторизовался?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, typescript, nestjs, prisma

работаю со стеком React + Nest + PostgreSQL + Prisma + TS. При попытке получить профиль моего юзера мне выдает, что профиля юзера не существует.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подозреваю, что метод `byId` где-то не передает юзера, но найти не могу, где. Помогите пж.

Файл `user.controller`, где происходит этот гет запрос:

```js
import { Body, Controller, Get, HttpCode, Param, Patch, Post, Put, UsePipes, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Auth } from 'src/auth/decorators/auth.decorator';
import { AuthDto } from 'src/auth/dto/auth.dto';
import { RefreshTokenDto } from 'src/auth/dto/refresh-token.dto';
import { CurrentUser } from 'src/auth/decorators/user.decorator';
import { UserDto } from './user.dto';

@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

 
  @Get('profile')
  @Auth()
  async getProfile(@CurrentUser('id') id: number) {
    return this.userService.byId(id)
  }

  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
  @HttpCode(200)
  @Auth()
  @Put('profile')
  async getNewTokens(@CurrentUser('id') id: number, @Body()
  dto: UserDto) {
    return this.userService.updateProfile(id, dto)
  }
  

  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
  @HttpCode(200)
  @Patch('profile/favorites/:productId')
  async toggleFavorite(
    @CurrentUser('id') id: number,
    @Param('productId') productId: string) {
    return this.userService.toggleFavorite(id, +productId)
  }
}
```

Файл `user.service`, где по айдишнику insomnia и должна получать пользователя:

```js
import { BadRequestException, NotFoundException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma.service';
import { returnUserObject } from './return-user.object';
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';
import { UserDto } from './user.dto';
import { hash } from 'argon2';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

    async byId(id: number, selectObject: Prisma.UserSelect = 
        {}) {
        const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({where: {
            id
        },
        select: {
            id: true,
            email: true,
            name: true,
            password: true,
            phone: true,
            favorites: {
                select: {
                    id: true,
                    name: true,
                    price: true,
                    images: true,
                    slug: true
                }
            },
            ...selectObject
        }
    })
    if (!user) { throw new Error('User not found.') }
    return user
}
    
    async updateProfile(id: number, dto: UserDto){
        const isSameUser = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {email: dto.email }
        })

        if (isSameUser && id != isSameUser.id) 
            throw new BadRequestException('Email already in use.')
        
        const user = await this.byId(id)
        
        return this.prisma.user.update ({
            where: {id},
            data: {
                email: dto.email,
                name: dto.name,
                phone: dto.phone,
                password: dto.password ? await hash(dto.password) :
                user.password
            }
        })
    }
    async toggleFavorite(userId: number, productId: number) {
        const user = await this.byId(userId)

        if (!user) throw new NotFoundException('User not found.')

        const isExists = user.favorites.some(product => product.id === productId)

        await this.prisma.user.update({
            where: {id: user.id},
            data: {
                favorites: {
                [isExists ? 'disconnect' : 'connect']: {
                    id: productId
                }
                }
            }
        })

        return 'Success'
    }
}
```

Помогите пж, когда найдете ошибку.

UPD: Поменял /api/users/profile на /api/user/profile, инсомния здесь пишет такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я залогинился:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Товарищи специалисты, нужна ваша помощь...

Comment: скорее всего, приложение просто не находит роут, который должен обработать этот запрос. проверьте всё там

Comment: @nörbörnën Вы про user.controller? просто там вроде есть роут хендлер `@Get("profile")`, подскажите, с ним ли что-то не так?

Comment: не разбераюсь в беке и в инджектах, но вроде путь должен быть user/profile, а запрос идет в users/profile

Comment: @Armen поменял кое-что в вопросе, гляньте пожалуйста. Остальные товарищи, прошу вашей помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @acurarsx login те должен был вернуть еще и токен по идее, и ты должен в каждом запросе отправлять этот токен серваку что бы он понимал КТО запрашивает данные.

Comment: @Armen Да, вышло. Отправил беарер токен и профиль пользователя явился сей же час. Также сменил `users` на `user`, поскольку существующим был только второй роут. В общем, огромное спасибо, успехов Вам!

Comment: @acurarsx не за что) удачи.